# Ref resource from another CloudFormation without output?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-service-catalog

Is it a way to reference a resource of another CloudFormation which is not outputted?

For example, in file1.yaml

```
Resource:
  SG1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    ....
```

And in file2.yaml, I will need to reference SG1

```
  SGMSKClusterIgress6:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      SourceSecurityGroupId: SG1 # How to reference SG1 here
      GroupId: !ImportValue MySecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: 443
      ToPort: 443
```

I know if there is `Outputs` in the file1.yaml, for example,

```
Resource:
  SG1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    ....
Outputs:
  SG1Output:
    Value: !Ref SG1
    Export:
      Name: File1SG1
```

I can use it in file2.yaml as

```
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !ImportValue File1SG1 # SG1 output name
```

What if it's not outputted? Do I has to modify file1.yaml to add the `Outputs` section and update the provisioned product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes for referencing resources in terms of CloudFormation, you should use outputs.
In case that you don't have access to file1.yaml, you can create a parameter in file2.yaml where you specify security group id and reference it in resource creation

Comment: Thanks. I may create a parameter for it so I don't need to update the product of file1.yaml. Should I create the SSM Parameter? (Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>)? SG1 is quite widely used in the account.

Comment: BTW, if file1.yaml was recreated and the SG1 has a new ID. How to make sure all depended products be updated?